# how to change to query in delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

```
procedure TGateScanForm.ebContainerKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  Found: Boolean;
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    ebContainer.ValidateEdit(True);
    if not BookingContainer.Active then BookingContainer.Open;

    Found:= BookingContainer.Locate('no_container', ebContainer.Text, []);

    if Found then
    begin
      no_booking:= BookingContainer.FieldByName('no_booking').Value;
      no_bc11:= BookingContainer.FieldByName('no_bc11').Value;
      no_container:= BookingContainer.FieldByName('no_container').Value;
      statCont:= BookingContainer.FieldByName('status_container').Value;
      statBooking:= BookingContainerstatus.Value;
      bProses.Enabled:= True;
      Key := VK_TAB;
    end
    else
    begin
      bProses.Enabled:= False;
      BookingContainer.Close;
      ShowMessage('Nomor Container tidak ditemukan');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The qusetion is how i can convert the below line to query.

> Found:= BookingContainer.Locate('no_container', ebContainer.Text, []);

Comment: What do you want to query? What is BookingContainer?

Comment: bookingcontainer is zeos component there is zquery

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, you may use :

```
function Found(S : string) : boolean;
begin
  try
    **Unsafe code:**

    MyQuery.SQL :=  Format('SELECT NO_CONTAINER FROM TABLE_BookingContainer 
       WHERE NO_CONTAINER = ''%s''',[S]);

    **Safe code:**

    MyQuery.SQL := 'SELECT NO_CONTAINER FROM TABLE_BookingContainer 
       WHERE NO_CONTAINER = :p);
    MyQuery.Params.ParamByName('p').AsString = s;


    MyQuery.Open;

    result := MyQuery.FieldByName('NO_CONTAINER').Value <> null;
  finnaly
    MyQuery.Close;
  end;
end;
```

to execute function may use :

```
....
if Found(ebContainer.Text) then
  .......
```

Comment: You know what happens if you enter e.g. `1'; DROP TABLE NO_CONTAINER; SELECT '1` into that edit box ?

Comment: @TLama I perfectly know about `SQL Injection`. I also know how to protect the database on server side.

Comment: Great. Then why did you write this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what for Dataset you use but something like this can search on the database.

```
BookingContainer.Close;
BookingContainer.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE no_container= :no_container';
BookingContainer.Parameters.ParamByName('no_container').Value := ebContainer.Text;
BookingContainer.Open;
```